HP/TANDEM TACL is possible to mask a column in a table? obviously ALTER TABLE maybe?
Im trying to mask a columns on some tables, to show a string when someone makes a select statement. But as u know, mask is not available on tandem, so i was thinking about a cobol routine maybe, its possibly or am i missing sumthin?
I try using alter table, but like i said, its not working.
